# Wait for previous action execution

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Let's assume we have two buttons. The first button executes the action with a delay  of 1000ms, while the other executes it with a delay of 2000ms. When clicking a button, I want to wait for it's execution and only after that, allow actions from the other button.

For example, clicking button two, and then button one, should only result in the action two button being executed (basically the action of button1 will be ignored, because action2 has not yet been executed). How can that be achieved using the rxjs library?

```
const btnOne = document.querySelector('#btn1');
const obs1 = rxjs.fromEvent(btnOne, 'click').pipe(
    rxjs.operators.delay(1000)
);

const btnTwo = document.querySelector('#btn2');
const obs2 = rxjs.fromEvent(btnTwo, 'click').pipe(
    rxjs.operators.delay(2000)
);

const generalObs = rxjs.merge(obs1, obs2).pipe(
    rxjs.operators.take(1),
    rxjs.operators.repeat()
);

generalObs.subscribe(result => console.log(result.target));
```

Comment: Have a look at [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Comment: @Mirakurn - Thank you, but please take into consideration that I want to achieve this using the rxjs library

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question correctly. Can i say that you just want to be able to disable buttons while any other async action is in progress? Or is pressing button 1 a prerequisite for pressing button 2?

Comment: @Davy Yes, I just want to "disable" (not really disable, but not initiate any action) buttons while any async action is in progress

Comment: This is what my answer below demonstrates, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this stackblitz: it demonstrates the use of the [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html) operator to achieve the behavior you describe.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a6spvp

The different map operators are amongst the most important and frequently used operators. Check the article below for a better explanation of what you can do with [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html), [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) or [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html).

https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-higher-order-mapping/

Once you have read the article: use the stackblitz i posted and replace [exhaustMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/exhaustmap.html) with [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html), [concatMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) or [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) and see how that affects the behavior ;)